# Div positioning CSS

Tags: css, web

I dynamically add `div` tag with `class="col-sm-3`" from javascript to its parent div (`position: relative`) and when some div were not on the same size, this happens (from the image). All I want is that, when the panel count is equal to 5 or more, it will position to the left most part.

[image]

Comment: Maybe float: left?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [MatchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) plugin if you want the boxes to be aligned and dont mind having some empty space inside.